# Where does Visual Studio 2010 run from when performing unit tests in C#?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Say I have a program that requires file I/O in the executable directory. Where would the executable for unit tests be located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code you can call [Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

If the loaded file was shadow-copied you need to use [CodeBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.codebase.aspx) to get the original location:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing a debug output using StdOut in test results, it appears that it runs in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
```